# Changing the colour of tkinter menubar

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code, what I'm trying to do is change the color the the menubar to be the same as my window. I have tried what you see below, adding to `bg="#20232A"` to `menubar` but this seems to have no affect..

My Question: The below image is the window (albeit a snippet of the window), it showcases both the menubar and background. I want the menubar to be the same color as the background seen below, how can I achieve this?

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

config = {"title":"Editor", "version":"[Version: 0.1]"}

window = Tk()
window.title(config["title"] + " " +config["version"])
window.config(bg="#20232A")
window.state('zoomed')

def Start():
    menubar = Menu(window, borderwidth=0, bg="#20232A") # Tried adding background to this, but it doesent work

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    window.config(menu=menubar)

Start()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What OS is this on?

Comment: It's on windows. Python 3.6.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change the color of the menubar on Windows or OSX. It might be possible on some window managers on linux, though I don't know for certain.

The reason is that the menubar is drawn using native widgets that aren't managed by tkinter, so you're limited to what the platform allows.

Comment: Is there an alternative solution? Something similiar to menubar but allows for bg?

Comment: @Chris You can write your own class to occupy topmost part of a window I guess.

Comment: @Chris: you can simply not assign a menu to the root window, and instead put a frame with menubuttons at the top. It won't quite look or behave like a normal menubar, though you can get pretty close. It really depends on if you want something to look and function in a standard way, or look and function slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up deciding just to stick with the standard look, I guess it's at least a familiar aesthetic and pops out from the rest of the darker theme.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux it is possible:

```
def main():

    root =Tk()
    menubar = Menu(root, background='lightblue', foreground='black',
               activebackground='#004c99', activeforeground='white')  
    file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=1, background='lightblue', foreground='black')  
    file.add_command(label="Receive")  
    file.add_command(label="Issue")  
    file.add_command(label="Track")  
    file.add_command(label="Search")  
    file.add_command(label="Allocate")  
    
    file.add_separator()  
    
    file.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)  
    
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Goods", menu=file)  
    edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
    edit.add_command(label="Undo")  
    
    edit.add_separator()  
    
    edit.add_command(label="Cut")  
    edit.add_command(label="Copy")  
    edit.add_command(label="Paste")  
    edit.add_command(label="Delete")  
    edit.add_command(label="Select All")  
    
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Accounts", menu=edit)  
    help = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
    help.add_command(label="About")  
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)  
    
    root.config(menu=menubar)  
    ex = MainWin()
    root.geometry("2000x1391")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just add foreground and background attributes.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from Brian Oakley's response. The menu bar on Linux (at least on my Linux Mint installation) renders the desired color.

[image]