# Tkinter: Change the menu bar and title bar colors

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to change the color of the menu bar and that of the title.

Here is the example of what I would like to have.

[image: example]

Is it possible?

Comment: You can look over here  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49088785/12132509

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To give an example of what you are trying to do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x200")
        self.configure(background='black')
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)
        
    def startMove(self,event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def stopMove(self,event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def moving(self,event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x)
        y = (event.y_root - self.y)
        self.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))

    def exit(self):
        self.destroy()


def save():
    print ('save')
    return None
def add():
    print('add')
    return None

  

class MenuBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=1, relief='raised')
        self.master=master
        self.configure(background='black',
                       cursor='hand2')

        file = tk.Menubutton(self, text='File',
                             background='black',
                             foreground='white',
                             activeforeground='black',
                             activebackground='white'
                             )
        file_menu = tk.Menu(file,tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label='save', command=save,
                              background='black',
                              foreground='white',
                              activeforeground='black',
                              activebackground='white'
                              )
        
        file.config(menu=file_menu)
        file.pack(side='left')

        edit = tk.Menubutton(self, text='Edit',
                             background='black',
                             foreground='white',
                             activeforeground='black',
                             activebackground='white'
                             )
        edit_menu = tk.Menu(edit,tearoff=0)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='add', command=add,
                              background='black',
                              foreground='white',
                              activeforeground='black',
                              activebackground='white'
                              )

        edit.config(menu=edit_menu)
        edit.pack(side='left')

        close = tk.Button(self, text='X', command=lambda:root.exit(),
                          background='black',
                          foreground='white')
        close.pack(side='right')

def show():
    print('show')
    return None
def ex_it():
    print('exit')
    return None

class MainFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, bd=1, relief='raised', text='MainFrame', background='black', foreground='white')
        self.master=master
        self.note = tk.Label(self, text='Your typed chars appear here:',
                             background='black',
                             foreground='white',
                             )
        self.note.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self, style='My.TEntry')
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=3, sticky='ew')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.b_frame=tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        self.b_frame.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='w')
        self.sh_b = tk.Button(self.b_frame, text='Show', command=show)
        self.ex_b = tk.Button(self.b_frame, text='Exit', command=ex_it)
        self.sh_b.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
        self.ex_b.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='w', padx=5)

root = App()

menubar = MenuBar(root)
menubar.pack(side='top', fill='x')

mainframe = MainFrame(root)
mainframe.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

menubar.bind("<Button-1>", root.startMove)
menubar.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", root.stopMove)
menubar.bind("<B1-Motion>", root.moving)

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.element_create("plain.field", "from", "clam")
style.layout("My.TEntry",
             [('Entry.plain.field', {'children': [(
                 'Entry.background', {'children': [(
                     'Entry.padding', {'children': [(
                         'Entry.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                                       'sticky': 'nswe'})], 'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                                     'border':'2', 'sticky': 'nswe'})])
style.configure("My.TEntry",
                 foreground="white",
                 fieldbackground="grey")

root.mainloop()
```

Have fun with it!

### Explaination

First, I've created 3 objects using classes and they look like this:

The App*lication* / our window that inharets from Tk()

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Then the Menubar which inharets from Frame and looks like:

```
class MenuBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=1, relief='raised')
```

and the MainFrame which inharets from the LabeFrame class of tkinter:

```
class MainFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, bd=1, relief='raised', text='MainFrame', background='black', foreground='white')
```

To learn more about classes and the init method [[click]](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)
To understand the syntax `self.` [[click]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709832/13629335)

Let's take a closer look to the App:

---

```
self.geometry("400x200")
self.configure(background='black')
self.overrideredirect(1)
self.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

- with [the geometry method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) we are define the `width=400` and `height=200` in pixels.
- Then we configure the background with the line:

```
self.configure(background='black')
```

- After this we use the [overrideredirect method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method) of tkinter which is clearly doing:

> Sets or gets the override redirect flag. If non-zero, this prevents
> the window manager from decorating the window. In other words, the
> window will not have a title or a border, and it cannot be moved or
> closed via ordinary means.

- and we finally use the [attributes method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.attributes-method) for Toplevels and set the argument topmost to true that does:

> (Windows) If set, this window is always placed on top of other
> windows. Note that in this release, this attribute must be given as
> “-topmost”.

---

The biggest problem after using overrideredirect is that you can't move your window anymore, cause there is no border/Title- or Menubar of the window manager anymore. So we need to carry it by ourself with using this code:

```
def startMove(self,event):
    self.x = event.x
    self.y = event.y

def stopMove(self,event):
    self.x = None
    self.y = None

def moving(self,event):
    x = (event.x_root - self.x)
    y = (event.y_root - self.y)
    self.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
```

And what this code does is to get the current mouse postion by clicking/Button-1 with the [event manger](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

event.x or event.y means:

> The current mouse position, in pixels.

event.x_root or event.y_root means:

> The current mouse position relative to the upper left corner of the
> screen, in pixels.

and by subtracting the one from the other we get the offset, that we need for our [geometry method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) to *"move"*.

---