# Change color menubar and canvas window ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I would like to change the color of my menubar and the canvas of my window in black. But with the `ttk.style` and `config`, but I can't find the process to change this.

I would like to change the top of window, what's highlighted. And I don't think it's possible to change this. I'm working on Window, and I would like create my "Style".

```
    import tkinter as tk

    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from datetime import *
    from tkinter import filedialog

    from ctypes import *
    from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


    try:
        windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(c_int(1))
        Width = 1920
        Height = 1080
    except:
        print('Error Display Quality')
    #----------------------------------Tkinter Principal --------------------------------------------------------------------

    class Window_main:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            amundi_color = "#00a0e3"
            myred = "#3A3A3A"
            withe = "#FCFAFA"

            # fenetre 1
            parent.title("Weekly Report")
            parent.configure(background= amundi_color)
            # parent.wm_attributes("-topmost",True)
            #Taille
            parent.minsize(600,350)
            parent.geometry("1440x810")


            self.style = ttk.Style()
            #self.style.theme_use("vista")

            self.style.theme_create( "style_amundi_black", parent="alt", settings={
            "TFrame": {
                "configure": {"background": myred } },
            "TLabel": {
                "configure": {"background": myred } },
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {"background": myred } },
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": { "background": myred,'font':('Arial',10), "foreground":withe},
                "map":       {"background": [("selected", amundi_color)],
                              "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] } } } )

            self.style.theme_use("style_amundi_black")

            menubar = Menu(parent)
            filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
            filemenu.add_command(label="Ouvrir dossier", font=("Arial",10))
            filemenu.add_command(label="Ouvrir fichier Source", font=("Arial",10))
            filemenu.add_command(label="Ouvrir code source", font=("Arial",10))
            menubar.add_cascade(label="Emplacement", menu=filemenu)

            modifier_source = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
            modifier_source.add_command(label="Modifier le fichier Source",font=("Arial",10))
            modifier_source.add_command(label="Generer le nouveau CSV",font=("Arial",10))
            menubar.add_cascade(label="Fichier Source", menu=modifier_source,font=("Arial",10))

            helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
            helpmenu.add_command(label="Procedure",font=("Arial",10))
            menubar.add_cascade(label="Aide", menu=helpmenu,font=("Arial",10))



            #self.labelframe1 = LabelFrame(parent,background='white',relief = 'sunken',labelanchor ='n')
            #self.labelframe1.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand="yes",pady=20,padx = 10)


            self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(parent,width=1440, height=810)
            self.my_notebook.pack(expand=1)

            self.dashboard = Frame(self.my_notebook,width=100,height=100,background='White')
            self.dashboard.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
            self.my_notebook.add(self.dashboard,text='DashBoard')

            self.dashboard = Frame(self.my_notebook,width=100,height=100,background='White')
            self.dashboard.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
            self.my_notebook.add(self.dashboard,text='Perf')



            parent.bind("<Configure>",self.conf)
            root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.Destroy_Window)

            #Assemblage du menu
            parent.config(menu=menubar)
            parent.mainloop()

        def conf(self,event):
                print (root.winfo_width())
                print (root.winfo_height())
                #print (root.winfo_geometry())
                self.my_notebook.config(height=root.winfo_height(),width=root.winfo_width())

        def Destroy_Window(self):
            root.destroy()
            sys.exit()


    root = Tk()
    timer = Window_main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: I would like to change the top of window, what's highlighted]

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks you !

Comment: You can't change the `Menubar` color. I built an entire menu and dropdown system from scratch because of this exact reason.

Comment: Ok, thank you and for the first line in top  (With the title) ? It's possible to change the background color ?

Comment: Nope. Not with tkinter. You could set a theme in Windows and change it to whatever color you want.

Comment: You can look over here and may just take the MenuBar class from, it isnt perfect but it does some kind of what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63128772/13629335