# Change Tkinter menu bar color (Windows)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, themes, customtkinter

I'm trying to adapt the theming of my file menu in a tkinter based application to the rest of the application.

My application is using customtkinter for most of its theming.

Unfortunately I can't find a solution to make my file menu even adapt to the system color settings.
My windows system is currently in Dark mode, but the File menu still appears light.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

here is my code so far:

```
menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menu_bar)

# Create the "File" menu
file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

# Create a submenu for "Import" option
qr_menu = tk.Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
qr_menu.add_command(label="Save QR Code", command=lambda: save_qr_code(url))
qr_menu.add_command(label="Show QR Code", command=lambda: show_qr_code(url))

file_menu.add_command(label="Import additional language", command=import_additional_language)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save Session", command=save_session)
```

[image: Image that shows the tkinter menu bar using light color although the system color is set to dark]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the colour of tkinter menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088785/changing-the-colour-of-tkinter-menubar). Btw you can always reimplement the menu with basic `tkinter` widgets like `tk.Frame`, `tk.Button` and `tk.Toplevel` but that will take quite a bit of code. I tried to do that [here](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/main/src/menu.py) but I don't know how stable it is.